# dynamic created fields

Tags: jquery

I have created dynamically the fields using Clone method.  How can I name these controls uniquely? I have a radio button and the text fields. Now I have to hide and show controls when the Radio button clicked.How can I get the ID or name of the radio button? I appreciate any help.

Comment: what is you code when you clone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiddle with cloning: http://jsfiddle.net/eFkC7/3/

```
$(":radio").click(function() {
    var radioID = $(this).attr("id");
});
```

OR

```
$("input[name=radioGroupName]").click(function() {
    var radioID = $(this).attr("id");
});
```

Comment: @nav100 added cloning to the fiddle example

Answer (score 0):

you can use `$(element).attr("name");` or `$(element).attr("id");`

```
attr( attributeName )
```

more infos : [Jquery .attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Comment: How can I find out which control was clicked?

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to use the click event with [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/):

```
$("input").live("click", function() {
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```